# Почему запрос к Яндекс.Переводчику выдаёт ошибку 403?

Tags: c#, .net, http-status-code-403, яндекс-переводчик

Пытаюсь сделать запрос на перевод к Яндекс.Переводчику, но вылетает исключение с кодом 403. При попытке сделать запрос в стоке браузера вылетает это:

```
{
    "code" : 401,
    "message" : "API key is invalid"
}
```

При этом ключ API валиден, пробовал даже с новым ключом - результат такой же.
Код выглядит так:

```
string yandex = Uri.EscapeUriString("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + key + "?text=hello?lang=en-ru");

xNet.Net.HttpRequest req2 = new xNet.Net.HttpRequest();
xNet.Net.HttpResponse resp2 = req2.Get(yandex);
```

Пробовал различные escape-функции - не помогло.

Answer (score 6):

У вас получается URL такого вида:

```
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key={key}?text=hello?lang=en-ru
```

Однако это некорректно - несколько параметров в URL разделяются амперсандами(`&`), а вовсе не дополнительными знаками вопроса:

```
string yandex = Uri.EscapeUriString("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + key + "&text=hello&lang=en-ru");
```

А вообще - рекомендую посмотреть на нормальные библиотеки для работы с REST-сервисами, например [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), либо стандартный [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Очень сильно затупил... спасибо тебе :D